# jQuery selector of optional types

Tags: javascript, jquery

This jQuery selector tries to match `input` elements which have any of the following types `[text | number | email | tel]`
It is failing to match the elements. how can it be done? Thx

```
$('input[type="text"][type="number"][type="email"][type="tel"]')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a comma separated selector:

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"]')
```

Another option is:

```
$('input').filter('[type="text"],[type="number"],[type="email"],[type="tel"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

With something like this :

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"]')
```

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Input can match only one type at a time. Try multiple selectors instead.

In the case below whichever it finds first will be executed.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){

  console.log($('input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"]').val());
  
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<input type="number" />
<input type="email" />
<input type="tel" />
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

If you want to get all the value just iterate over all the elements that the selector returns

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){

  $('input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"]').each(function() {
  
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
  
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<input type="number" />
<input type="email" />
<input type="tel" />
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```